# Importing data via api call for vis.js

Tags: vis.js

Following is the code I am trying for vis.js .I am trying to visualize data present on my server in json format through xmlhttprequest. But all it shows is blank screen as output. I am running the following code on server. Reponse shows status 200 and blank screen

```
<html>
      <head>
        <script
          type="text/javascript"
          src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"
        ></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script
          type="text/javascript"
          src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.19.1/vis.min.js"
        ></script>
        <link
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.19.1/vis.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css"
        />

        <style type="text/css">
          #mynetwork {
            width: 800px;
            height: 800px;
            border: 1px solid rgb(134, 29, 29);
          }
        </style>
      </head>

      <body>
        <div id="testdiv"></div>
        <div id="mynetwork"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          // function loadXMLDoc() {
          var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          //var xhttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              //var data1 = this.responseText;
              console.log(xhttp.responseText);
              var data1 = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
              document.getElementById("testdiv").innerHTML =
                "<h1>Data Export Successful</h1>";
            }
            //};
            xhttp.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:5000/neo4j/export", true);
            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            xttp.setRequestHeader(
              "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
              "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type,Accept"
            );
            //loadXMLDoc();
            xhttp.send();
          };
          var data = {};
          var options = {};
          var container = document.getElementById("mynetwork");
          var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Any errors on your console?

Comment: No there is no error !

Comment: Can you see the `Data Export Successful` message on the page? If not please post the value of `data1` variable or value of `xhttp.responseText`.

Comment: No..even that is not shown